# Is there any hope to find extrema points of the given function $f_z (x,y)$ without using the Hessian method?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix, extreme-value-analysis

I have a three-variable function for $(x,y)\in[-\pi,\pi]$ and $z>0$

$f_z (x,y)=A(z)(\cos x+\cos y)+B(z)(\cos 2x+\cos 2y)+C(z) (\cos x \cdot\cos y),$

in which the real functions $A(z),B(z),C(z)$ can be positive or negative. I am looking for those points $(x,y)$ at which the function $f_z (x,y)$ reaches its extrema (both minimum and maximum).

**Question**

> I may probably find those points by using the Hessian method for obtaining the extrema. I am asking if there is any simpler/obvious way to find those points.

Comment: A first step could be to set $a=A(z),b=2B(z),c=C(z)$
$$g(u,v)=a(u+v)+b(u^2+v^2-1)+cuv$$
and look for the extrema of $g$ on $[-1,1]^2.$

Comment: May I ask you to explain a bit more in detail how to find the extrema on $[-1,1]^2$?. Should I use the Hessian determinant? Sorry, my major is not mathematics; so, I will be grateful if you could kindly send me an example link so that I learn how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a first step to simplify the question but at the moment, I don't have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a family of functions indexed by a parameter $z$,and wish to study for each fixed choice of $z$ what are the  extrema of the function $f_z(x,y)$. Following up on Anne Bauval's comment, the quadratic function $g(u,v)$ may have interior critical points  where (i) $g_u=a + 2 b u + cv=0$ and also (ii) $ g_v= a +2b v +cu =0$.  (They are interior  solutions  if they lie in the region $-1<u<1$ and $-1<v<1$.)

Solving this pair of linear equations we get

$u =v = \frac{ a( c-2b)}{D}$ where in your problem $D= 4b^2-c^2$ is the discriminant. The classification of these interior critical points of $g$  involves the use of the Hessian matrix, specifically  first checking the sign  of the discriminant $D$ and then the sign of $b$.

(You  also get another family of critical points where $0=D=4b^2=c^2$; these satisfy $ u=-v$. The Hessian test is indeterminant in this case, and more complicated tests are needed to classify these.

Here is a visual check on the location of critical points in a worked example. I plotted the solution surfaces  of (i) and (ii) with 3D graphics and see where they intersect in space.
[image: Solution surfaces intersecting]

This is the intersection set of the two surfaces. Basically the set of critical points consists of three blue curves, Two curves lie in the plane where $u=v$ and one curve lies in the plane $u=-v$. Looking down from above you see they lie in two perpendicular planes.  [image]

(Note that two curves merge in a disaster at one place).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My major is not Math and I should think about it to get it, But as you mentioned I already knew that I should check the boundaries of my rectangular domain as well in addition to the Hessian determinant.